# Date parsing exception?

Tags: android, date

I am trying to parse a date in this format "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm". The input that I have provided is "12-12-17 06:00" but it gives me an exception.

Here is the code,

```
final public static SimpleDateFormat FRMT_2_DD_MM_YY_HH_MM=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm", Locale.US);

public static Date parseDateInFormat_Date()
    {

 try {
           return FRMT_2_DD_MM_YY_HH_MM.parse("12-12-17 06:00")
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return null;

        }

}
```

This gives me a ParseException when trying to parse.Here is what all I tried.

1. `final public static SimpleDateFormat FRMT_2_DD_MM_YY_HH_MM=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());`
2. `final public static SimpleDateFormat FRMT_2_DD_MM_YY_HH_MM=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm");`

Both of them threw a parse exception and I don't know why ?

Comment: You should add the stacktrace of the exception you get.

Comment: @MehdiB. No stacktrace..

Comment: no stack trace because u havent printed anything, try `e.printStackTrace()`` before `return null` line..

Comment: @AalapPatel Yes yes I am not a fool that I don't understand programming It doesn't print any stacktrace even with `e.printStackTrace();`

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me. Try it.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy hh:mm", Locale.US);
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "date: "+format.parse("12-12-17 12:50"));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "date:Exception ");
    }
```

Output:

```
date: Tue Dec 12 00:50:00 EST 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems fine, try printing the complete stack trace using e.getPrintStackTrace() to see the exact position in the passed string which is causing the ParseException.
Ready to further help.

Comment: No stacktrace at all.

Comment: Can you update your question as per your new changes in code in order to print stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. I've just tested it and it worked fine.

1- You forgot a semi-colon at the end of `return FRMT_2_DD_MM_YY_HH_MM.parse("12-12-17 06:00");`

2- Since no Exception stacktrace is attached, What I suspect to be the problem are the imports you're using.

This is what you should be using:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
```

Comment: I am using the above imports.

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution,returning the `FRMT_2_DD_MM_YY_HH_MM.parse` was the root cause of the problem not sure why though this worked fine.

```
public static Date parseDateInFormat_Date()
    {
Date date;

 try {
           date= FRMT_2_DD_MM_YY_HH_MM.parse("12-12-17 06:00")
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            date=null;

        }

return date;
}
```